# problem in json parsing in android app

Tags: android, json, parsing

in my app when i hit an url i am getting a return data as an json array. it is as follows

```
{"Status":[{ "img_path": "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/images/thumb140/1316145577.jpg", 
             "img_path": "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/images/thumb140/1316146270.jpg", 
             "img_path": "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/images/thumb140/1316146473.jpg", 
             "img_path": "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/images/thumb140/1316147003.jpg" } ]}
```

From the above result i am trying to parse out the urls and i am trying to store it in an array list. Following is my code

```
 try{
        JSONArray get_post_status = json.getJSONArray("Status");
        for (int i = 0; i < get_post_status.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject e = get_post_status.getJSONObject(i);
        if(e.equals("img_path"))
        {
            Get_post_image_array.add(e.getString("img_path"));
        }
        }
```

But in my arraylist i am getting only the last url from the result. How to get all the urls in the arraylist.

Pls help me.......

Comment: Did you know that you can use `example.com` as an example host name? `example.com` is a reserved domain name, as specified in [RFC 2606](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The returned JSON is invalid.

Shortening the data, looking only at the structure:

```
{
    "Status":
        [
            {
                "img_path": "a", 
                "img_path": "b", 
                "img_path": "c", 
                "img_path": "d"
            }
        ]
}
```

We can see that the array (enclosed in `[]`) only contains one element; the object enclosed by `{}`. This object has several instances of the same key, `"img_path"`. This is not valid. Your parser apparently ends up with keeping only the last instance of it.

The JSON ought to look more like this:

```
{
    "Status":
        [
            "a", 
            "b", 
            "c", 
            "d"
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is invalid.

`{"Status": [ {"img_path": "blah, blah"}, {"img_path": "blah2, blah3"}]}`

is what you want. Essentially, you were setting the same key in an object over and over, not creating a list of objects.